# javascript access of css transforms for opera and ie

Tags: javascript, css, transform

i am making this global function which will simply change an element's transform property.
This is what i have.

```
function transform(element, value) {
    if(element.style.webkitTransform) element.style.webkitTransform = value;
    else if(element.style.MozTransform) element.style.MozTransform = value;
}
```

I also want to add opera and ie to the above function. i have opera running with me so i can test opera but i dont have ie 9. Also i cant figure out how can i access opera's either. Can anyone please help?

I want something like this

```
function transform(element, value) {
    if(element.style.webkitTransform) element.style.webkitTransform = value;
    else if(element.style.MozTransform) element.style.MozTransform = value;
    else if(element.style.msTransform) element.style.msTransform = value;
    else if(element.style.oTransform) element.style.oTransform = value;
}
```

Comment: Hi, Perhaps you could use some well-known js framework, such as jQueryUi, where all this stuff is already implemented, with nice performances.

Comment: @vaugham yes, i am aware of jQuery but i am trying to move away from it. Plus its not production code, i am still learning this stuff.. so i guess i should use the new stuff instead of jquery.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can always just set them all. The other browsers will ignore styles they cannot understand.

```
function transform(element, value) {
    element.style.webkitTransform = value;
    element.style.MozTransform = value;
    element.style.msTransform = value;
    element.style.OTransform = value;
}
```

Comment: but that will throw an error in console, right? also i have opera and `oTransform ` does not seem to be working :O

Comment: ok it doesn't throw error but the `oTransform` is definitely not working in latest opera. and i can't check ie because i dont have ie9 installed on my machine.

Comment: @Achshar : Try `element.style.OTransform = value;`

Comment: yup! apparently it requires capital O. Thanks!

Comment: +1 :: Can you please list also alternatives for `*transform-origin` parameter(s)? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

With older versions of Opera, based on Presto engine, you should do forced precision to reduce the side effects of the 'early' implementation of CSS 2D transforms, such as:

```
var action = "scale(" + value.toPrecision(4) + ")";
element.style.transform = action;
element.style.oTransform = action;
```

I don't believe this has negative impact on modern implementations.